# Message Queueing - Handling multiple responses simultaneously - C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, msmq

I've a business application where i've a master application and multiple slave applications (geographically distributed) connected to each other. All the slave application interact through master application and master application should handle all the incoming requests as well as respond to the previous requests.

We're dealing with huge volume of data getting transferred between the master and child sites. So i need to handle all the pouring incoming requests and responses simultaneously and effectively. To be precise, i want all the nodes to communicate in a fail-safe manner.

I was looking at [MSMQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Message_Queuing) for our requirement. I want you guys' opinion as how best this can be handled in .NET using MSMQ or any other proprietary or Open Source message queuing tool.

Thank you.

Regards
NLV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSMQ is a reliable messaging protocol and will be able to achieve what you described above. If you look into WCF offerings, fundamentally all the messaging types will allow you to handle concurrent requests quite efficiently. The good thing about using WCF 
is that through the configuration you can tweak to use different binding, transport protocols and size of the concurrent requests or threads so that you can keep adjusting until you find what is most optimal for your situation. It also takes care of the plumbing code for you and you dont necessary have to code specifically and tied to msmq only.